# Class has already been added to output. Please remove duplicate copies

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have some app, which works fine, if I run it on device.

But now, I need to write unit tests for this app, and I have a problem, when I try to run some unit test.

Here is my app *build.gradle*:

```
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
            mavenCentral()
            maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
            classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
        }
    }
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    configurations {
        all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
        all*.exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services'
    }

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 21
        buildToolsVersion "19.1"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.lodoss.shopsterhood"
            minSdkVersion 9
            targetSdkVersion 21
            versionCode 15
            versionName "2.0.1"
        }
        dexOptions {
            preDexLibraries = false
            incremental = false
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }

        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
            exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
            exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
        }

        lintOptions {
            abortOnError false
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: ['*.jar'])
        compile project (':appcompat')
        compile project(':DragSortListView')
        compile 'com.github.chrisbanes.actionbarpulltorefresh:library:0.9.9'
    //    compile 'com.vk:androidsdk:1.3.6'
        compile project(':facebook')
    //    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.2.1@aar') {
    //        transitive = true;
    //    }
        compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:1.3.0@aar') {
            transitive = true;
        }


    //    androidTestCompile 'com.squareup.assertj:assertj-android:1.0.0'
    //    androidTestCompile 'com.squareup.assertj:assertj-android-support-v4:1.0.0'
    //    androidTestCompile 'com.squareup.assertj:assertj-android-play-services:1.0.0'
        compile 'com.jayway.android.robotium:robotium-solo:5.2.1'
    //    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.0'
    //    androidTestCompile ('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.0') {
    //        exclude module: 'support-annotations'
    //    }
    //    androidTestCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:1.3'

    }
```

And here is *build.gradle* of module, which gets compile error, when I trying to run unit test:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "19.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
        incremental = false
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Here is my test:

```
package com.lodoss.shopsterhood.activity;

import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;
import com.lodoss.shopsterhood.Activity_Main;
import com.robotium.solo.Solo;

/**
 * Created by Boris on 27.05.15.
 */
public class EmailRegistrationTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<Activity_Main> implements ActivityTestCaseConstants {

    private Solo solo;

    public EmailRegistrationTest() {
        super(Activity_Main.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity());
    }

    @Override
    protected void tearDown() throws Exception{
        solo.finishOpenedActivities();
    }

    public void testEmailRegistrationWithCorrectData(){
        // check that we have the right activity
        solo.assertCurrentActivity("Wrong activity", Activity_Main.class);

        Activity_Main activity = (Activity_Main) solo.getCurrentActivity();
    }
}
```

I know, that it does nothing useful, but it not running.

I have **3** error.

**First error**:

> Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':appcompat:dexDebugTest'.
>
> > com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
> >       /opt/adt-bundle-linux/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702/sdk/build-tools/19.1.0/dx
> >     --dex --no-optimize --output /home/alexander/projects/shopster-gradle/appcompat/build/intermediates/dex/test/debug
> >     /home/alexander/projects/shopster-gradle/appcompat/build/intermediates/classes/test/debug
> >     /home/alexander/projects/shopster-gradle/appcompat/build/intermediates/bundles/debug/classes.jar
> >     /home/alexander/projects/shopster-gradle/appcompat/libs/android-support-v7-appcompat.jar
> >     /home/alexander/projects/shopster-gradle/appcompat/build/intermediates/bundles/debug/libs/android-support-v7-appcompat.jar
> >     /home/alexander/projects/shopster-gradle/appcompat/libs/android-support-v4.jar
> >     /home/alexander/projects/shopster-gradle/appcompat/build/intermediates/bundles/debug/libs/android-support-v4.jar
> >     Error Code:       1   Output:     UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
> >       java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added:
> >     Landroid/support/v7/widget/SearchView$OnSuggestionListener;
> >               at com.android.dx.dex.file.ClassDefsSection.add(ClassDefsSection.java:122)
> >               at com.android.dx.dex.file.DexFile.add(DexFile.java:161)
> >               at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:685)
> >               at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:634)
> >               at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$600(Main.java:78)
> >               at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:572)
> >               at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
> >               at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
> >               at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
> >               at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:596)
> >               at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:498)
> >               at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:264)
> >               at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
> >               at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)
> >               at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)      UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:     java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already
> >     added: Landroid/support/v4/util/TimeUtils;
> >               at com.android.dx.dex.file.ClassDefsSection.add(ClassDefsSection.java:122)
> >               at com.android.dx.dex.file.DexFile.add(DexFile.java:161)
> >               at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:685)
> >               at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:634)
> >               at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$600(Main.java:78)
> >               at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:572)
> >               at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
> >               at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
> >               at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
> >               at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:596)
> >               at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:498)
> >               at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:264)
> >               at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
> >               at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)
> >               at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)      2 errors; aborting

**Second** error:

> Error:Gradle: Class
>   android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.OnSuggestionListener has already
>   been added to output. Please remove duplicate copies.

**Third** error:

> Error:Gradle: Class android.support.v4.util.TimeUtils has already been
>   added to output. Please remove duplicate copies.

After researching *first* stacktrace, I found this lines:

> /home/alexander/projects/shopster-gradle/appcompat/libs/android-support-v7-appcompat.jar
>
> /home/alexander/projects/shopster-gradle/appcompat/**build/intermediates/bundles/debug/libs/android-support-v7-appcompat.jar**
>
> /home/alexander/projects/shopster-gradle/appcompat/libs/android-support-v4.jar
>   /home/alexander/projects/shopster-gradle/appcompat/**build/intermediates/bundles/debug/libs/android-support-v4.jar**

If I correct understand, gradle added to *build* directory this libraries, then trying to dex its with original libraries and throws exception.

I tried to remove its by hand, but it not helps...

Additionaly, I can't remove this libraries(jars) from module, because it's very old project, and this libraries have specified revision / version. Only this jars are compatable with this *appcompat* module. When I deleted its and added as **gradle dependecy**, disappeared some resources from *appcompat* module. In other words, **adding this libraries as gradle dependecies is unacceptable decision.**

I try to run test using *Intellij IDEA 14*.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

**EDITED**

*Hash of my **support-v4** library*: `7C2158F2ABA8503DF83F92C934508E2F`

*Hash of **v7-appcompat** library*: `75B6D02AA52729CA3F7B62DB1AF465EE`

Answer (score 0):

Robotium is a test library, should not be included like this

```
compile 'com.jayway.android.robotium:robotium-solo:5.2.1'
```

Instead try

```
androidTestCompile 'com.jayway.android.robotium:robotium-solo:5.2.1'
```

Comment: It not helped. Error still appears